# Is there any way to optimise/configure QtWebKit to increase JavaScript/rendering performance?

Tags: qt, extjs, qtwebkit

We're creating a Qt app which is basically a QtWebKit window for viewing a web application. The web application's frontend is written in ExtJS and it is running very slowly in some parts (e.g. some screens with multiple grids or complex layouts). My question is: is there a way of configuring the Qt app to make increase the performance of its JavaScript/rendering engine?

Thanks!

Comment: Try qt5. Anyway HTML rendering is slow compared to QtQuick.

Comment: Are you confident about the root cause of the perfomance slow down??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to tune webkit, so you can't tune it from Qt, either. But that doesn't mean you can't do anything. Here is a checklist of things you can try:

1. Make sure the performance is actually lost in the place where you think by **measuring** it with a profiler. I'm wrong 90% of the time when guessing what causes bad performance problems. Have a look at how many reputation I have and then think hard whether you are *really* sure you can do better :-)
2. If a profiler isn't an option, add timing information to the code.
3. Is it also slow in a normal web browser? If so, try to improve the JavaScript code. There are tools to run/profile that as well. Some are even built into your web browser.
4. Consider implementing part of the UI without ExtJS (and the overhead it brings along). Do you really need a full-fleshed out grid to display static data that can't be sorted? Maybe a plain HTML table will do.
5. Try a newer version of Qt. 5 just came out and it contains a more recent version of webkit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The performance is poor in other browsers too, I just thought there might be a way of "turbo-charging" QtWebkit to be more powerful! The part of the program that's problematic is a part where we have to have quite a complex layout, which obviously causes the poor performance. I think I may just have to put up a 'please wait' screen while that part initially loads.